# Assign variable or return immediately

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

Hello I was looking for a way to do something like this in Python 3:

```
def do_something(inp):
    tmp = inp.property or return "Input property is missing"
    tmp_fancy=""
    #
    # Do some fancy stuff 
    #
    return tmp_fancy
```

To clarify, I want to return from the function immediately in case "input" is `None` and otherwise proceed. The code above is just an example to show you what I'm looking for.

Basically I'm looking for a shorthand which serves this purpose.

Comment: `return` is a statement.  You can't nest it inside a boolean expression (or anywhere else, really).  You'll just have to do `if not input: return "Missing!"`.

Comment: I wan't to assign it directly to the variable. I'm not going to use the input parameter any further. In my case it's some property of any instance (=longer)

Answer (score 0):

Well you can't have `return` placed like that since it's a statement. You  can use a simple `if` check to accomplish this:

```
if inpt is None:
    return "Input is missing"
```

don't use the name `input`, though, you'll mask the built-in `input` inside that function.

Comment: It's OK to mask a builtin if that builtin has no business being used in your function (e.g. if your function does some string magic, it probably has no business reading from stdin).

Comment: @jim-fasarakis-hilliard could we simply use `if not inpt:` condition?

Comment: @Kevin I'd still urge people not to, there's not much benefit in confusing anyone who reads your code by re-using names they've associated with different functionality.

Comment: @an0o0nym Sure. I simply prefer not to have all the logic indented and, instead, use an `if` check to catch the exceptional case.

Comment: In my case input is just an instance or null and and I want to have let's say tmp=input.abc. So the if check would be fine but I'm looking for a shorthand.

Comment: @Jim Fasarakis-Hilliard This code is used only by myself so I don't care about probably confusing someone

Comment: @Nexolight sometimes someone is actually you after a couple of months. It's just a good practice note that I always state in these cases.

Comment: @an0o0nym The best alternate so far